# Connection reset by peer GO

Tags: http, go

I'm trying to do a request in GO but I always receive "Connection reset by peer" error. The following code shows how I'm doing the request:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
client := = &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

defer resp.Body.Close()
fmt.Println(resp.Body)
```

...and I receive:

```
Get https://example.com: read tcp 1.2.3.4:1234->5.6.7.8:5678: read: connection reset by peer
```

When I do curl https://example.com I receive response form the server.
Why can't I do the request in GO?

Comment: The server is closing your connection. Do you control the endpoint, and can you check the logs there? Is this really the complete code you're using, because `fmt.Println(resp.Body)` doesn't print anything useful.

Comment: I receive an error from resp, err := client.Do(req) so the body is nil

Comment: With curl I can do the request, the problem is the Go code

Comment: can you do a ping to that server ?

Comment: Yes I can. I receive the response from the server with curl

Comment: Again, the server is closing the connection on you for _some_ reason. Try creating a request that looks exactly like a curl request, and see if it's filtering out unexpected clients.

Comment: But i'm doing this. My request in go is similar to curl. I read that go works open streams. I don't know if it can be the problem.

Comment: Not a similar request, _exactly_ the same request. That is assuming it's getting through the handshake at all. This doesn't look like a handshake error, but maybe that's being reset before it even starts. Trace the connection on the wire, or add some debugging to the handshake code. Does the server share a ciphersuite with Go? What does it support for TLS?

Comment: Something is amiss here for sure. "read tcp 1.2.3.4:1234->5.6.7.8:5678" looks like some dummy example data just based on the IPs and ports. example.com does not resolve to either of those IPs. The code also does not show what is being assigned to `url`, so this is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When I run [this](https://play.golang.org/p/APxGjTJcd9) locally (since you can't dial out from playground), it works - I get `200 OK`. There's something wrong outside of the code shown.

Comment: Can you connect to your host in your local network? Check logs on it. There could be different settings. For example `curl` can be condifured to use some proxy by default, and `go` not.

Comment: NOt sure if this a similar issue being faced, but in my case it was more towards using the externalAPI and issue with intermittent network. One way to identify that the issue is with the network connection, is via chunking. In my case I was calling an external API and my calls to them are chunked, so after receiving approximately 50 items , I endup with the issue reported above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if I use it against a URL like `https://example.com`. Are  you sure you are passing it the correct URL?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://example.com"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("OK")
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    str := string(bytes[:])
    fmt.Printf("%s", str)
}
```